# CSRF Struts 1.3 saveToken/isTokenValid BACK BUTTON

Tags: struts, csrf, back

I am using the saveToken / isTokenValid in a very old struts application. I have been able to implement the saveToken and isTokenValid attributes to prevent a CSRF attack, but if I press the BACK BUTTON then try to submit the same form I hit my error. Is it possible in struts to prevent a CSRF attack using these utilities but allow the ability to go back and resubmit a form?

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking CSRF and resetting the token on each page, which means the old tokens were invalid. I instead only save the token once and reset it only where it needs to be.

Comment: are you resetting the token on the result page?